# I want to get some value from other class dynamicly for ex:

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, variables

My code

```
 public class Data{
  Public class Friend{
public int[] jane = {somthing};
public int[] frank = {somthing};
public int[] john = {somthing};
}}
```

I wanna use this variable in other class like this:

```
class GetData{
int[] getName = Data."className"."friendName";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class GetData{
int[] getName = Data."className"."friendName";
}
```

inherit the getdata class to your second class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement GetData{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@android remote control, So, what you are trying to achieve, what do you mean by dynamic here? please be clear with your question.